# Python UI to enter 2 parameters

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I want to create a simple UI so the user can enter an integer and a string parameter. I was hoping to use something as simple as QInputDialog(), but as far as I can tell that only works with 1 parameter.

```
inputDialog = QtGui.QInputDialog()
myInt, ok =  inputDialog.getInt(inputDialog, 'Enter Params', 'Int', 1)
```

Is there a simple way to do something like:

```
inputDialog = QtGui.QInputDialog()
myInt, myString, ok =  inputDialog.getInt(inputDialog, 'Enter Params', 'Int', 1), inputDialog.getText(inputDialog, 'Enter Params', 'Text', 1)
```

I started looking at PyQt, but that just seems like such an overkill for something so basic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: whynot just get a string input from the user that eg `"user_string,5"` and split it? ... rather than having 2 inputs... I think you will have to make a custom dialog if you really need 2 inputs

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard Qt dialog with multiple fields. What you can do is either use two dialogs in sequence or else have the user enter both values in a single field, then split them in your code.  E.g.:

```
inputDialog = QtGui.QInputDialog()
myText, ok  = inputDialog.getText(inputDialog, 
              'Enter number, a space, then text', 'Data', '')
if ok:
    myInt, _, myText = myText.partition(" ")
    try:
        myInt = int(myInt)
    except ValueError:
        myInt = 0
```

Neither is very good from a user experience perspective, though.

Comment: That's what he said he was trying to avoid.